# Open Tkinter Window so it sits on start menu bar

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I would like to have a Tkinter window open at the bottom right of the screen or where ever the start bar is. Much like when you click on the battery icon on your laptp and the box pops up. My code currently hides it behind the start menu bar. I would essentially like it at the bottom right but sitting on top of the start menu bar. Also, not sure how to account for things if the start menu is not at the bottom.

My Code:

```
from Tkinter import *

def bottom_right(w=300, h=200):
    # get screen width and height
    screen_width = root.winfo_screenwidth()
    screen_height = root.winfo_screenheight()
    # calculate position x, y
    x = (screen_width - w)
    y = (screen_height-h)
    root.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (w, h, x, y))
root = Tk()
bottom_right(500, 300)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You shouldn't assume that the Start Menu bar is at the bottom of the screen. It's fairly easy to move the Taskbar and Start Menu to one of the other screen edges. I have mine at the top.

Comment: Good point. modified, question to be on start menu, not at the bottom.

Comment: Are you actually trying to create an application that lives in the system tray along with the battery icon, volume icon and clock and so on?

Comment: @patthoyts yes, ultimately, but I really just want it positioned down there next to the task bar, like when you open any of the applications you mentioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `win32api`'s `.GetMonitorInfo()` to find the 'working area' of the monitor, which is the area of the monitor without the taskbar. Then, seeing where the taskbar is, you can place the window in a corner of the working area. See this example:

```
import win32api
import Tkinter as tk

for monitor in win32api.EnumDisplayMonitors():
    monitor_info = win32api.GetMonitorInfo(monitor[0])
    if monitor_info['Flags'] == 1:
        break

work_area = monitor_info['Work']
total_area = monitor_info['Monitor']

width = 300
height = 200

side = [i for i in range(4) if work_area[i]!=total_area[i]]

# Left
if side ==[0]:
    x = str(work_area[0])
    y = str(work_area[3]-height)
# Top
elif side == [1]:
    x = str(work_area[2]-width)
    y = str(work_area[1])
# Right
elif side == [2]:
    x = str(work_area[2]-width)
    y = str(work_area[3]-height)
# Bottom
elif side == [3]:
    x = str(work_area[2]-width)
    y = str(work_area[3]-height)
else:
    x = str(work_area[2]-width)
    y = str(work_area[3]-height)

geom = '{}x{}+{}+{}'.format(width, height, x, y)

root = tk.Tk()
root.configure(background='red')
root.geometry(geom)
root.overrideredirect(True)
root.mainloop()
```

Note that I've used `overrideredirect` to get rid of the frame of the window, since this messes with the placing a bit.

Comment: This yields an error:     `monitor_info = win32api.GetMonitorInfo(1)
pywintypes.error: (1461, 'GetMonitorInfo', 'Invalid monitor handle.')` but this sounds like it would work.

Comment: Oh weird, works fine here. You can try `win32api.GetMonitorInfo(win32api.EnumDisplayMonitors()[0][0])`?

Comment: that yields: `{'Device': '\\\\.\\DISPLAY1', 'Work': (-1920, 151, 0, 1231), 'Flags': 0, 'Monitor': (-1920, 151, 0, 1231)}` I'm new to this and not sure what to do with this. Passing in DISPLAY1 as a string does not work.

Comment: Great, just `use monitor_info = win32api.GetMonitorInfo(win32api.EnumDisplayMonitors()[0][0])` then. On my pc 'Flags' is 1, so maybe you could use 0 instead of 1. But using the line I just said is probably safer across pcs.

Comment: Wait, not so great. Your 'Work' and 'Monitor' values are the same. Also they have a negative value, so I don't really understand what's going on there.. What does `win32api.EnumDisplayMonitors()` return?

Comment: Do you maybe have more than one monitor? Then the values you just posted could be your second monitor on which there is no taskbar? If so, `win32api.GetMonitorInfo(win32api.EnumDisplayMonitors()[1][0])`  might give you the info about your other monitor

Comment: You're right, I have two monitors. How would I detect if someone had two monitors because if they don't this would probably yield an out of range error.

Comment: I believe you should find the one with 'Flags': 1, I'll update my answer. I also added an `else` for if the taskbar is hidden.

Answer (score 1):

What you are calling the 'start menu bar' is usually called the taskbar, at least on Windows.  `root.iconify()` minimizes the root window to the taskbar, wherever it happens to be, just as when one clicks [_] in the upper right of the window.  Clicking on the icon de_iconifies it, just as with any other app.

```
root = tk.Tk()
root.iconify()
<build gui>
root.deiconify()
root.mainloop()
```

is a common pattern in a polished app when the  part takes long enough to cause potentially visible construction activity.  I believe putting the gui in a frame and packing the frame as the last step has the same effect (of hiding construction).

Comment: Does the function `deiconify` still exists for tkinter in Python 3?

Comment: I was asking because I think once I tried to use it, but the behaviour was not the expected... but thanks :)