# resizing tkinter window for full screen

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I know there's a ton of postings like this one. However, I don't think I've come across one with quite this question.

I know the following will grab the current width and height of the screen and set the tkinter window to be this size and then similarly for the canvas should we wish to have one.

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
width = root.winfo_screenwidth()
height = root.winfo_screenheight()
root.geometry("%dx%d" % (width, height))
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, .....)
canvas.pack(fill = "both", expand = True)
```

However, what I've noticed using this is that there is always a portion of the tkinter window that is cut off from the taskbar at the bottom of the screen. I find this to be a bit annoying, especially if you have labels or or other such features that you wish to be visible at the bottom.

Is there anyway to get around this? I know we could subtract an offset factor from the height to account for a possible taskbar at the bottom of the screen, but then this awkwardly displaces the tkinter canvas.

Comment: What platform are you on? I can guess it's not Mac, but Windows 7, Windows 8, Ubuntu, …?

Comment: Sorry, I should have included that windows 7 but im assuming this applies to windows 8

Comment: On Windows, AFAIK, there's no way for Tkinter to get this information directly—but, if instead of explicitly going fullscreen, you set your window state to zoomed, it'll pick the right size for you. Let me try to dig up the details.

Comment: Or try this, on the off chance I'm remembering right: `root.state("zoomed")` or `root.state("zoom")`.

Comment: That worked beautifully actually. I used root.state("zoom"). That was a much simpler fix than I was expecting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe there's no way to actually get the taskbar information from inside Tkinter on Windows.

But you don't have to. If you set the main window's state to "zoomed", Tkinter will ask Windows to maximize your window, and Windows will take care of fitting you in with the taskbar—and also handle any other weird decorations you might have, and handle auto-hiding taskbars, and so on.

```
root.state('zoomed')
```

As far as I can tell, Tkinter doesn't document this value (the [`state`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/wm.htm#Tkinter.Wm.state-method) docs in the Tkinter book say only 'normal', 'iconic', 'withdraw', and 'icon' are allowed).

But, as is so often the case, if you turn to the Tcl/Tk docs, you discover that Tkinter's documentation is just incomplete. Even in [the tutorial](http://www.tkdocs.com/tutorial/windows.html), it mentions:

> On most systems, you can temporarily remove the window from the screen by iconifying it. In Tk, whether or not a window is iconified is referred to as the window's state. The possible states for a window include "normal" and "iconic" (for an iconified window), as well as several others: "withdrawn", "icon" or "zoomed".

The Tk [reference documentation](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/wm.htm) for `wm state` says:

> … either normal, iconic, withdrawn, icon, or (Windows and Mac OS X only) zoomed.

Also, IIRC, you can use "zoom" for "zoomed" (and also "withdraw" for "withdrawn", "iconified" or "iconify" for "iconic", and "iconwindow" for "icon"), but Tk tries to be inconsistently friendly.

Comment: Although `root.state('zoomed')` is absolutely the right answer here, there actually is a way to get the size of the screen excluding the taskbar on windows using `win32api`'s `GetMonitorInfo()` which gives the "working area" of the screen. I've used it in my answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27825902/3714930). Note that only subtracting a part of the height to compensate for the taskbar still won't give the desired result (except when using `overrideredirect`), since the border of the window is still around the size specified.

Comment: @fhdrsdg: Yes, that's why I said "from inside Tkinter". There's a whole MSDN page on the right way to simulate the same thing maximized mode does without being in maximized mode, and you can definitely do all of it from pywin32 (or just ctypes, if you'd rather write uglier code than require extra dependencies).

Comment: Ah right, missed that part. I agree that from Tkinter only that's not possible. Do you by any chance have a link to that MSDN page? Even though I'll probably never use it, I'd like to read that.

Comment: @fhdrsdg: No link; I only know it exists because many years ago (2000/XP days), I worked on a taskbar replacement app that had to make all the same APIs work the same, and I was glad they'd documented everything. (Although I suppose that just proves it once existed, not that it exists… but my experience is that Microsoft isn't nearly as bad as some companies *cough*Apple*cough* at eradicating old documentation for no good reason.)

Comment: No problem, thanks anyway. I'll just search some more hoping it's still around.